# Mysql, bridge table with fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So i have another table, this needs to include data such as raceTime and the raceResult (1st, 2nd, 3rd etc) and whether they have paid (yes/no) Is this the correct way to place it in a bridge table? Following the specification I have it says to.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

That looks right.

I would also wonder whether `paid` should be `NOT NULL`, since you could argue that that is not actually crucial to recording a result. If paying is a prerequisite to registration, that should preclude adding the record altogether.

Comment: The paid section is for a race, they have to have paid before being allowed to take part in the race: so they can enter the race at any time but have to pay before the race day to compete